# Which sites to link exchange with?

Tags: seo, pagerank, backlinks, link-building

When approaching websites for link exchange (presumably, this is a worthwhile link building exercise?), what factors should one look at to assess whether or not the site is worthwhile the effort?

Should PageRank be considered -- or is that dead? Moz Page Authority?

Also, is there a limit of links I should have linking to other sites? I don't want Google thinking our site is a link farm.

Comment: You should find better Domain Authority & Page Authority websites. If you can find .edu links in related content then these are the best. Also, if it is possible, ask backlinks from inline content instead of sidebar/footer friends/links section.

Comment: Do not ***exchange*** links. Seek sites that will link to you, however, exchanging links (linking back) is an easy linking pattern to sniff out and will likely get you into trouble. Better yet, seek organic links.

Answer (score 1):

> what factors should one look at to assess whether or not the site is worthwhile the effort

there are only few factors:

- the linking site should be good
- it should be thematically relevant
- the link to you should look naturally

Common sense and Google's [webmaster guidelines](https://goo.gl/HdN2Hu) help to understand, what is meant with `good`, `relevant` and `naturally`.

Comment: I do believe Google considers link exchanges as poor quality so the real answer should be "don't do it".

Comment: "The linking site should be good?" -- what factors makes a site "good?" Should I look at Page Authority and Domain Authority? Are all link exchanges bad?

Comment: @JohnConde yes, indeed i thought about it. but such answer seemed to me to be hypocritical: most webmasters do link exchange, more or less according to webmaster guidelines. Google doesn't prohibit it explicitly, it just list, which kinds of link exchange are violations against webmaster guidelines, like here: https://goo.gl/fx4Du